# Fat Domain Events or thin domain events

Tags: events, domain-driven-design

I have doubts about what is the best approach to publish my domain events. I have two use cases:

- The user can create a question with answers
- The user can add an answer to a given question

One of the invariants are:

- A question must have at least 2 answers and at maximum 5 answers.

I have designed a aggregate `Question` with a list of `Answer` entities, and it `Question` constructor I verify that invariant.

Related to first use case, my doubt is related on the domain event I should publish.

My first approach is this domain event:

```
public class QuestionCreated {
  private final String questionText;
  private final List<Answer> answers;
}
```

I don't feel good with `answers` property because it is a list of `Answer` entity, but I don't know how do it better.

Or second approach, would you do two domain events `QuestionCreated` and `AnswerCreated` and when I create a question, the aggregate will publish a `QuestionCreated` event and one `AnswerCreated` for each answer in `answers` list?

For the second use case, add an answer to question, following the aggregates principles, I would save the `Question` aggregate, with the new answer. In this case I also have doubts about the domain event to publish, a `QuestionUpdated`, similar to `QuestionCreated`, or `AnswerAdded` only with the answer information.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a question can't exist with zero or one answers, I think it's overall better to include at least two answers in the "genesis" event for `Question` (i.e. `QuestionCreated`).  Otherwise, you'll have to model a proto-question which has zero or one answers and be sure to never treat that as a `Question`.

For the adding an answer case, it's generally a good practice to avoid `Updated` events, because a major part of the value in modeling domain events is that they express the context (e.g. the "why") of the change in addition to what changed.  `Updated` events don't capture that context.  So I'd definitely use an `AnswerAdded` event.

I would strongly consider having the `QuestionCreated` event have exactly two answers:

```
public class QuestionCreated {
  private final String questionText;
  private final Answer firstAnswer;
  private final Answer secondAnswer;
}
```

If 3-5 answers were supplied at creation, those would then be emitted as `AnswerAdded` events (or the otherwise identical but differently named to capture context `AnswerCreated`).  By encoding `QuestionCreated` in this way, we ensure that there's no way to express the creation event with fewer than 2 answers ("make illegal states unrepresentable"... we'll handwave away `null`), and we also allow at least the possibility of not allocating a `List`.